# Python - R square and absolute sum of squares obtainable by scipy.optimize curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am fitting curves using curve_fit. Is there a way to read out the coefficient of determination and the absolute sum of squares?
Thanks, Woodpicker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), optimization with `curve_fit` gives you

> Optimal values for the parameters so that the sum of the squared error
>   of f(xdata, *popt) - ydata is minimized

Then, use `optimize.leastsq`

```
import scipy.optimize
p,cov,infodict,mesg,ier = optimize.leastsq(
        residuals,a_guess,args=(x,y),full_output=True,warning=True)
```

with this for `residuals`:

```
def residuals(a,x,y):
    return y-f(x,a)
```

`residuals` is the method returning difference between true output data `y` and model output, with `f` the model, `a` the parameter(s), `x` the input data.

Method `optimize.leastsq` is returning a lot of information you can use to ***compute RSquared and RMSE*** by yourself. For RSQuared, you can do

```
ssErr = (infodict['fvec']**2).sum()
ssTot = ((y-y.mean())**2).sum()
rsquared = 1-(ssErr/ssTot )
```

More details on what is `infodict['fvec']`

```
In [48]: optimize.leastsq?
...
      infodict -- a dictionary of optional outputs with the keys:
                  'fvec' : the function evaluated at the output
```

Comment: I tried to follow you, but did not succeed. Do I need to use both curve_fit AND leastsq? And can I not use somehow pcov from my curve_fit? Accoring to the doc, curve_fit already uses leastsq - or is the information I need to calculate r square not handed over from leastsq to curve_fit?

Comment: The main thing I am confused about if the " a_guess " in the leastsq function - what does this mean? Thanks...

Comment: yes, what is exactly `a_guess`? The way you wrote the code, `a_guess` is not defined...

Comment: I'm also curious what a_guess is. @Woodpicker, you've marked this answer as the solution. Have you figured out what a_guess is? Would you mind to explain it, please?